# Get number of post who belongs in two taxonomies!

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I need a way to figure this in the image! I have two taxonomies (Band, City) in my custom post type and I need in my custom archive page to have all the posts who belong in each taxonomy! Is there a way to achive this?

E.g post who has taxonomy1 **term1** and taxonomy2 **term1** has 2 posts, post who has taxonomy1 **term1** and taxonomy2 **term2** has three posts,post who has taxonomy1 **term1** and taxonomy2 **term3** has one posts,post who has taxonomy1 **term1** and taxonomy2 **term4** has three posts and go on! After the taxonomy 1 **term2** and taxonomy1 **term1** has one posts and thats goes on!

[image: Final result]